# ParamValidationError when using `create_view` for boto3 resource-explorer-2 at organization level

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-resource-explorer

We are trying to create view for AWS resource explorer at organization level. We want to fetch all resources list for all the sub accounts under the organization account. We followed [create_view - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resource-explorer-2/client/create_view.html) to create the view:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('resource-explorer-2')
    response = client.create_view(
        Filters={ 'FilterString': '*' },
        IncludedProperties=[ { 'Name': 'ResourceType' }, ],
        Scope='organization_arn',
        ViewName='view_name'
    )
    return response
```

We are getting this error:

> ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
> Unknown parameter in input: "Scope", must be one of: ClientToken, Filters, IncludedProperties, Tags, ViewName.

I don't know why this error is coming up. Can anyone review the code and help me out?

Comment: def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('resource-explorer-2')
    response = client.create_view(
    Filters={
        'FilterString': '*'
    },
    IncludedProperties=[
        {
            'Name': 'ResourceType'
        },
    ],
    Scope='organization_arn',
    ViewName='view_name'
    )
    return response

Comment: Please add the properly formatted code to the question, not comments.

Comment: Are you running this code in an AWS Lambda function? Which version Runtime did you specify (eg `Python 3.12`)?

Comment: yes we are using python 3.12